# Java execution stops silently on variable assignment

Tags: java, debugging, httpclient, remote-debugging, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm trying to instantiate CloseableHttpClient (apache httpclient 4.3) in my maven project by executing:

```
HttpClients.createDefault();
```

but execution does not get to next line of my code.

Here is what I can see in debugger (`public CloseableHttpClient build()` method of `org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder` class):

```
public static final X509HostnameVerifier BROWSER_COMPATIBLE_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER
    = new BrowserCompatHostnameVerifier();
```

...

```
X509HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = this.hostnameVerifier;
if (hostnameVerifier == null) {
    hostnameVerifier = SSLConnectionSocketFactory.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER; // <-- last line executed, BROWSER_COMPATIBLE_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER is null here
}
if (sslcontext != null) { // <-- this step is not reached
```

...

In other words code execution is stopped on line equivalent to

```
X509HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = null;
```

without exception.

How is it possible?

NOTE. Not sure whether it worth to mention but just in case. I'm attaching IDEA debugger to process running on remote machine.

Comment: The debugger is not so hard to confuse. Maybe the source code it has does not line up with the debug info in the .class file.

Comment: Hello Marko, I've updated description with info that I'm using maven project and proper sources are downloaded automatically. Do you still think it is possible?

Comment: No, I don't think it's possible.